# How to limit window resize for UWP App

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to limit my App window Width to 800 px, is there any way to do so?
I tried SizeChanged event by doing some logic hack but actually it's executing after the Size is changed. So there's little bit of UI throttling.

Comment: Limit, meaning, it'll be the maximum width?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no way how to limit window size since your app could run in fullscreen mode when in table mode.

However, you can set [`MaxWidth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_MaxWidth) and/or [`MaxHeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_MaxHeight) properties on any `FrameworkElement`, for example on a page.

I've set both the properties to `500` on the red page and you can see the result here:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

There is built-in support only for the minimum window size limit.
For this use the `ApplicationView.SetPreferredMinSize` method, where you can set the preferred minimum height and width size of you window.

```
ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().SetPreferredMinSize(new Size(800, 800));
```

You need to call it in App.xaml.cs before `Window.Current.Activate();`

For the maximum there is no good way. I don't know better solution than call `ApplicationView.TryResizeView` method in the `SizeChanged` event.

Comment: That will not work, as maximum size that SetPreferredMinSize accept is 500*500

Answer (score 0):

In this [source](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ResizeAppView) is example how resize view.